# Realm data browser on Windows 10

Tags: realm

I manage to get export.realm using those code

```
package com.meow.meowmeow;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import io.realm.Realm;
import io.realm.RealmConfiguration;

/**
 * Created by Thien on 9/1/2015.
 */
public class RealmTool {
    private static String LOG_TAG = "RealmTool";

    //export to email
    public static void exportDatabase(Context context,RealmConfiguration configuration) {

        // init realm
        Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(configuration);

        File exportRealmFile = null;
        try {
            // get or create an "export.realm" file
            exportRealmFile = new File(context.getExternalCacheDir(), "export.realm");

            // if "export.realm" already exists, delete
            exportRealmFile.delete();

            // copy current realm to "export.realm"
            realm.writeCopyTo(exportRealmFile);


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        realm.close();

        // init email intent and add export.realm as attachment
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("plain/text");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "YOUR MAIL");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "YOUR SUBJECT");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "YOUR TEXT");
        Uri u = Uri.fromFile(exportRealmFile);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, u);

        // start email intent
        context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "YOUR CHOOSER TITLE"));
    }

    //import from assets
    public static RealmConfiguration importDatabase(Context context, String realm_file_name){
        RealmConfiguration defaultRealm = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(context).build();
        String dir = defaultRealm.getPath();
        AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
        try {
            InputStream is;
            is = assetManager.open(realm_file_name);
            File dest = new File(dir);
            if (dest.exists())
                dest.delete();
            copy(is,dest);
        }catch (IOException e){
            Log.e(LOG_TAG,"import database error");
        }
        return defaultRealm;
    }

    public static void copy(File src, File dst) throws IOException {
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(src);
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dst);

        // Transfer bytes from in to out
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
    }
    public static void copy(InputStream in, File dst) throws IOException {

        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dst);

        // Transfer bytes from in to out
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
    }

}
```

Now I want to check it out.
How to edit it in windows. 
The developer said they only has realm browser on Mac
But I am using windows 10.
So anyone have any ways or any tool to browser realm on Windows.
Thank you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*(Disclaimer: I'm the guy in charge of Realm Browser for Mac. :) )*

We hear you! Unfortunately, at the moment, to even consider a version of Realm Browser for Windows, we need to get Realm itself running on Windows to begin with! It's something we're absolutely working on, but obviously it's not a small amount of work; so we haven't got any release timelines yet.

For the time being, if you want to debug a Realm file from an Android app, there's actually a really cool open-source third party Android Realm browser app that you could potentially use instead: https://github.com/dmytrodanylyk/realm-browser

Sorry I couldn't bring any better news, but at the very least, I hope that helps in the interim. But we're 100% aware that having an equivalent version of Realm Browser on Windows would greatly help Android development on that platform.

Comment: The author of that app stated, on Sept 12, 2015, that the library is no longer supported.

Comment: @TiM please look into this question, related to realm studio for windows https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47505171/android-realm-database-decryption-failed

Comment: Sorry @Aks4125! I'm not involved with the development of Realm Studio.

Comment: @TiM I have also tried to open in realm browse in mac but still unable to open encrypted realm. anyways thanks for heads up.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution, there is third party's Stetho Realm plugin https://github.com/uPhyca/stetho-realm, Stetho is Android debugging bridge developed by Facebook. It also let you be able to see the Realm's data on your devices.

Answer (score 3):

I just wrote a trivial Realm Browser (Rebro) in form of an Android Studio plugin. Not sure how big is demand, it was more like a challenge. But anyway, here you go: https://github.com/Ghedeon/Rebro

Comment: @MarkBuikema it does.

Answer (score 1):

After checking all the old answers I thought of putting my latest research on this thread.

As per below link they don't have anything in place for windows yet. You are lucky if you are using mac.

https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/

But they have mentioned about utility build by facebook to browse and edit realm data.

http://facebook.github.io/stetho/

PS: Those of you who don't know how to debug application from chrome browser, you can go to inspect devices options by clicking three vertical dots on top right side on chrome.
    Visit More tools-->>Developer Tools-->>Again click on three vertical dots-->> more options-->>>Inspect Devices. After that you would see same UI as features in above link.